# Pipe a transform or readable stream to process.stdout

Tags: node.js, stream

I have the following code:

```
const pt = require('prepend-transform').default;
const writable = pt('[test-process]').pipe(process.stdout);
```

writable is the destination stream which is process.stdout, so if I write to writable, I just get stdout, without '[test-process]' prepended to each line. Note that `pt(x)` returns a transform stream.

On the other hand, if I do this instead:

```
const pt = require('prepend-transform').default;
const transform = pt('[test-process]');
transform.pipe(process.stdout);
```

and then I write to transform stream, no data seems to make it to process.stdout.

So I do I need to use a read stream instead of a transform stream to do this?

So instead of a transform stream, I tried using a readable stream:

```
  const data = [];
  const readable = new stream.Readable({
    read: function (size) {
     this.push(data.pop());
    }
  });

 readable.pipe(pt('[test-process]')).pipe(process.stdout);


 let log = function(){
     Array.from(arguments).forEach(function(a){
        data.push(a);
     });
  };
```

nothing gets written to stdout when I use readable like so.

Comment: After I tried the [example usage](https://github.com/ORESoftware/prepend-transform#usage) of  `prepend-transform` with no luck, I decided to use the ol' poke with console.log(), and found a way of using it :P  Hope you can extrapolate the working code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Using`'prepend-transform'` with a Readable Stream

---

If you do :

```
const PT =  require('prepend-transform')
console.log(PT)
```

You get :

```
{ default: [Function: default_1] }
```

So, you would have to do `PT.default('[test-process]')`

Here is a working code example (with readable stream) :

```
//:Example Readable Stream
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var rs = new Readable;
rs.push('beep ');
rs.push('boop\n');
rs.push(null);
//:PrependTransform Correct Usage Example
const PT =  require('prepend-transform');
rs.pipe(PT.default('[child stdout]')).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Example Output :

```
[child stdout]beep boop
```